# Relative ordering of non Spring security filters (like addFilterAfter, addFilterBefore)?

Tags: spring, sorting, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE and I have two filters (*java.servlet.Filter*) `RequestHeaderParseFilter` and `RequestLogFilter`. `RequestHeaderParseFilter` retrieves and set values from request header. And `RequestLogFilter` logs them. I have registered them using `FilterRegistrationBean`

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean requestHeaderParseFilter () {
  FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
  Filter requestHeaderParseFilter = new RequestHeaderParseFilter();
  this.beanFactory.autowireBean(requestHeaderParseFilter);
  registration.setFilter(requestHeaderParseFilter);
  registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
  return registration;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean requestLogFilter() {

  FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
  Filter requestLogFilter = new RequestLogFilter();
  this.beanFactory.autowireBean(requestLogFilter);
  registration.setFilter(requestLogFilter);
  registration.addUrlPatterns("/rest/*");
  return registration;
}
```

I want to order `RequestLogFilter` after `RequestHeaderParseFilter` in the filter chain. But I don't want to use `RegistrationBean.setOrder(int)`. In this situation I have the following choices and questions:

1. I tried using `addFilterAfter` available in Spring Security filter chain like below

   ```
   @Inject
   @Qualifier("requestLogFilter")
   private FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> filterRegistrationBean;

   .addFilterAfter(this.filterRegistrationBean.getFilter(), RequestHeaderParseFilter.class);
   ```

   Firstly, this throws an error `Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'. Cannot register after unregistered Filter class`. Which means `RequestHeaderParseFilter` was not registered in Security filter chain.

   Q1. **Do I need to explicitly register my filters with Spring Security filter chain?**

   Even if this works, It does not feel intuitive to add these filters to Spring Security filter chain since they have nothing to do with security.
2. Do not register these filters as Spring Security filters but rather as part of some generic filter chain.

   Q2. **Apart from Spring Security filter chain. Are there other filter chains available in Spring?**

   Q3. **Is there anyway I can use something like `addFilterAfter` to order my filters without using Spring Security filter chain?**